# Working out the start and end of a day. Swift

Tags: swift, date, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

I have a function to work out the start and end of a week which works as expected. I want to implement another function which works out the start and end of a single day. I have the code below however I get the following error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

```
public class Date {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    func calcStartAndEndDateForWeek(durationOccurance: Double) {
        print("Calculating start and end for week")
        let componentsWeek = calendar.components([.YearForWeekOfYear, .WeekOfYear], fromDate: date)
        let startOfWeek = calendar.dateFromComponents(componentsWeek)!

        print("start of Week = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfWeek))")

        let componentsWeekEnds = NSDateComponents()
        componentsWeekEnds.weekOfYear = 1
        let endOfWeek = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(componentsWeekEnds, toDate: startOfWeek, options: [])!

        print("End of the week = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(endOfWeek))")
    }


    func calcStartAndEndDateForDay(durationOccurance: Double) {
        print("Calculating start and end for day")
        let componentsWeek = calendar.components([.Minutes, .Seconds], fromDate: date)
        let startOfDay = calendar.dateFromComponents(componentsWeek)!
        print("start day = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfDay))")
    }

    init(){
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create a more generic function using the methods on `NSCalendar`:

```
func rangeOfPeriod(period: NSCalendarUnit, date: NSDate) -> (NSDate, NSDate) {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()    
    var startDate: NSDate? = nil

    // let's ask calendar for the start of the period
    calendar.rangeOfUnit(period, startDate: &startDate, interval: nil, forDate: date)

    // end of this period is the start of the next period
    let endDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(period, value: 1, toDate: startDate!, options: [])

    // you can subtract 1 second if you want to make "Feb 1 00:00:00" into "Jan 31 23:59:59"
    // let endDate2 = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Second, value: -1, toDate: endDate!, options: [])

    return (startDate!, endDate!)
}
```

Called as

```
 print("\(rangeOfPeriod(.WeekOfYear, date: NSDate()))")
 print("\(rangeOfPeriod(.Day, date: NSDate()))")
```

Putting it into your code:

```
public class Date {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    func rangeOfPeriod(period: NSCalendarUnit) -> (NSDate, NSDate) {
        var startDate: NSDate? = nil

        calendar.rangeOfUnit(period, startDate: &startDate, interval: nil, forDate: date)

        let endDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(period, value: 1, toDate: startDate!, options: [])

        return (startDate!, endDate!)
    }

    func calcStartAndEndDateForWeek() {
        let (startOfWeek, endOfWeek) = rangeOfPeriod(.WeekOfYear)

        print("Start of week = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfWeek))")
        print("End of the week = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(endOfWeek))")
    }


    func calcStartAndEndDateForDay() {
        let (startOfDay, endOfDay) = rangeOfPeriod(.Day)

        print("Start of day = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(startOfDay))")
        print("End of the day = \(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(endOfDay))")
    }

    init() {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    }
}

let myDate = Date()
myDate.calcStartAndEndDateForWeek()
myDate.calcStartAndEndDateForDay()
```

Comment: Oh wow thanks this works a treat! Something that i wanted to do next was make the end date 2 weeks from now. Would this be achievable with this function?

Comment: @JessMurray That depends. The function just gives you the range for a date and a given period of time. You can add 2 weeks to current day and use the function on the result.

Comment: Ok thanks I think i understand what you mean. If i wanted the weeks/days to increase by 2 rather than 1 would I have to change the duration from 0 to 1?

Comment: @JessMurray Nope, you shouldn't touch that function. Week duration is variable because of daylight saving time - there is always a week that is one hour longer or one hour shorter. Therefore, don't create durations manually. If you want to add weeks, create a new `NSDateComponents` and set `weekOfYear` to required amount of weeks to add. By the way, that duration is not equal to zero. The zero is just a default value. The actual duration is computated in `NSCalendar.rangeOfUnit(...)`.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help :) How can i change the week start day to monday rather than sunday?

Comment: @JessMurray The best way do to that is changing the locale on `NSCalendar` to a locale that starts weeks with Monday. Usually the locale is set to system locale so you shouldn't actually change that.

Comment: This seems to be causing problems how due to the clocks going forward. I have posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263743/calculating-startdate-and-enddate-of-a-day-based-on-todays-date-swift-2, would you be able to assist?

Comment: @JessMurray I have updated the code to use a safer calculation for the end date.

Comment: Thanks Sulthan this has fixed the start date however the end date is showing 23:00:00 +0000 rather than the expected 23:59:59 +0000

Comment: @JessMurray See my comment about subtracting 1 second.

Comment: Thanks. Its really odd, for month it shows '2016-03-01 00:00:00 +0000' (with 00:00:00 +0000 for the time )for the start date but for a day it has '2016-03-27 23:00:00 +0000' (with 23:00:00 +0000 for the time).

Comment: @JessMurray That's actually correct. That day was 1 hour shorter.

Comment: Oh i see. So for today at 23:55:00 it will be within the start date: 2016-03-27 23:00:00 and end date 2016-03-28 22:59:59?

Answer (score 0):

I was implementing something similar and went the following route:

```
extension Date {
    static var startOfToday: Date? {
        let date = Date()
        guard !date.isStartOfDay else { return date }
        return date
            .zero(out: .second)?
            .zero(out: .minute)?
            .zero(out: .hour)?
            .addingTimeInterval(-24 * 60 * 60)
    }

    private func zero(out: Calendar.Component) -> Date? {
        return Calendar.current
            .date(bySetting: out, value: 0, of: self)
    }

    private var isStartOfDay: Bool {
        let cal = Calendar.current
        let hours = cal.component(.hour, from: self)
        let minutes = cal.component(.minute, from: self)
        let seconds = cal.component(.second, from: self)
        return hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0
    }
}
```

Setting a component to zero will increment the next bigger component. So just setting the hour to zero will push the date to the next day at 00:00, unless of course the hour is already at zero. So to make it work for any date we have to zero out the seconds, minutes and hours (in that order). And to make sure we don't end up at the beginning of yesterday we first check if all values aren't already at zero.

I realize this is kinda hacky and probably not the best way to go about this, but it seems to work well enough for my use-case at least.

Getting the end of the day can be built on top of this by just adding another day.