# Calculating StartDate and endDate of a day based on todays date. Swift 2

Tags: swift, timezone, nsdate, nscalendar, nstimeinterval

I have the following function which i am using to calculate a start and end of todays date. It was working perfectly last week, i think it may have something to do with the clocks going forwards?

```
func rangeOfPeriod(period: NSCalendarUnit, date: NSDate) -> (NSDate, NSDate) {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var startDate: NSDate? = nil
        var duration: NSTimeInterval = 0

        calendar.rangeOfUnit(period, startDate: &startDate, interval: &duration, forDate: date)

        let endDate = startDate!.dateByAddingTimeInterval(duration - 1)

        return (startDate!, endDate)
}
```

When I try and calculate the start and end of a day using:

```
print("Start of Day = \(rangeOfPeriod(.Day, date: NSDate()).0), End of Day = \(rangeOfPeriod(.Day, date: NSDate()).1)")
```

I get the following, where the start and end date is 1hour behind what is expected:

```
Start of Day = 2016-03-27 23:00:00 +0000, End of Day = 2016-03-28 22:59:59 +0000
```

when i would expect:

```
Start of Day = 2016-03-28 00:00:00 +0000, End of Day = 2016-03-28 23:59:59 +0000
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because you are in the GMT+1 time zone....

Comment: Thanks, How do i change this?

Comment: I have updated the answer in the original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943023/working-out-the-start-and-end-of-a-day-swift/35943270?noredirect=1#comment60156482_35943270) so this probably a duplicate.

Comment: The *calculations* are correct (according to your local time zone). The default *output* of NSDate however is in UTC, "2016-03-27 23:00:00 +0000" *is* midnight in your time zone. If you search for "NSDate wrong by some hours" you'll find many similar Q&A's.